# Changing key during reduce phase

Tags: java, apache-spark, mapreduce

Let's say my (key,value) pairs are now these:

```
(word1,d1=1)
(word1,d2=1)
(word2,d1=2)
(word3,d1=1)
```

Is it possible to reduce to the following where the key is changed and the value is original number/number of times it appears?

```
(word1@d1, 1/2)
(word1@d2, 1/2)
(word2@d1, 2/1)
(word3@d1, 1/1)
```

I read the docs from Spark. The reduceByKey() will return me a dataset of (K, V) where V1,V2 -> V and the key would remain K. But in the above case, K will be K' and I have to update the V for different keys. Any ways I can achieve the above? Just started learning Spark and I'm confused now. Appreciate your help!!

Comment: can you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: I tried using countByKey() saved to a map variable which indeed tells me how many times it appears. Then I tried to map the same K,V pairs with the countByKey() values but it seems some of the results were 0 probably due to map-reduce nature? So I guess probably countByKey() won't work and I'm only left with reduceByKey()? I can't visualize how reduce will work out here?

Comment: Did you mean (word2@d1, 2/1) instead of (word2@d1, 2/2) in the question?

Comment: yes! overlooked that. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Connecting global count for word, can be done with both `countByKey` (broadcast join) and standard `join`. It is not perfectly clear what are the types, so let's assume:

```
val sc: SparkContext

val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("word1", "d1=1"), ("word1", "d2=1"), ("word2", "d1=2"), ("word3", "d1=1")
))
```

With `countByKey`:

```
val cnts = sc.broadcast(rdd.countByKey)
```

and `map`:

```
rdd.map { case (k, v) => (k, (v, cnts.value.getOrElse(k, 0L))) }
```

which `collected` gives:

```
Array((word1,(d1=1,2)), (word1,(d2=1,2)), (word2,(d1=2,1)), (word3,(d1=1,1)))
```

With `join`

```
val cntsRDD = rdd.mapValues(_ => 1L).reduceByKey(_ + _)
rdd.join(cntsRDD)
```

which `collected` gives:

```
Array((word2,(d1=2,1)), (word3,(d1=1,1)), (word1,(d1=1,2)), (word1,(d2=1,2)))
```

I'll leave reshaping the result, depending on the exact input types, as an exercise for the user.